# How to hide out a layout in Xamarin.forms C#?

Tags: c#, android, xamarin.android, xamarin.forms

I have a Stacklayout with switch control, when the switch values are true i have to show the layout and if the value changes to false i have to hide the layout. Based on some samples, i saw how to hide out a button but for hiding out a layout i can't find one. Can anyone suggest me how to do it in Xamarin.forms. Advance thanks guys for those helped me to solve the problem.

Switch.cs

```
void switchControl(object sender, ToggledEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.Value == false)
    {
        StackLayout view = this.FindByName<StackLayout>("employee");
        //hide the layout gone or invisible          
    }else{
        //show the layout visible
    }
}
```

Comment: I don't really understand what you are trying to do.. To put it simple; you have a switch which should show or hide a `(Stack)Layout`? The StackLayout has a `IsVisible` property, that isn't working?

Comment: ya i can see it but can you show me how to set layout to visible and invisible on toggle click control.

Comment: The code in your question is working so far right? You should probably move `StackLayout view = this.FindByName<StackLayout>("employee");` to outside of your `if statement` and inside your `if statement` add `view.IsVisible = true;` of `false` of course when you want to hide it.

Comment: i have done it but can u tel me how to set layout invisible or gone in Xaml

Comment: Ah, you never mentioned any `XAML` in your question. Could you show me the `XAML` code you have so far? You should probably do something like this: `<StackLayout x:Name="employee" IsVisible="{Binding NameOfSwitch.IsChecked}">...</StackLayout>`. Like this you can remove the `switchControl` method altogether.

Comment: @GeraldVersluis so thanks Gernald for spending your precious time for me.

Comment: Instead of setting it in Xaml i have set default view IsVisible=false in the code.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/80361/discussion-between-gerald-versluis-and-manoj).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

From our discussion I have gathered that you want to show/hide a layout by toggling a `Switch`, in `XAML`.

For this we will be using [data-binding](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/xaml/hh464965.aspx).

Set your `StackLayout.IsVisible` property to bind to the `Switch.IsChecked`, like this:

```
<StackLayout x:Name="employee" IsVisible="{Binding NameOfSwitch.IsChecked}">...</StackLayout>
```

Also you noted that the layout has to be hidden by default. To implement this we will set the `Switch` to be unchecked by default like this:

```
<Switch android:checked="false" android:textOn="Yes" android:textOff="No" />
```